# Call function only for children jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change not every element with ".grid" class in my colorTiles() but only these which are included in element.

```js
function renderGrid(element, settings) {
  $(element).append("<div class='grid'><div class = 'usernameSpace'>    </div></div>");
};
function colorTiles(grid, options) {
    $(".grid").each(function (index) {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor',getOptions(options).backgroundColor);
        return this;
    })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the issue is. Could you please edit the question to make your goal clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only target `.grid` elements within some other element, use a *descendant combinator* (a space) in your selector, e.g.:

```
$("selector-for-the-parent-element .grid").css(/*...*/);
```

or, if you have a jQuery object for the element (perhaps that's what `grid` is?), use `find`:

```
grid.find(".grid").css(/*...*/);
```

or if `grid` is a raw DOM element, use `$()` and `find`:

```
$(grid).find(".grid").css(/*...*/);
```

Also note that there's no need for that `each` at all:

```
function colorTiles(grid, options) {
    $(grid).find(".grid").css('backgroundColor',getOptions(options).backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: Works. I also need to modify another function:     $(".usernameSpace").each(function (index) {
So I have to find only usernameSpace which is in element